# How to make a new Dynamics Model Driven App available to a non-System Administrator user?

Tags: powerapps, dynamics-crm-365

I have created a new Model Driven App.  I have shared the app with a non-System Administrator user who also has Model Driven App read permission.  However, the user cannot see the new app.

Is there a step that I have missed?

Please advise.

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Documentation from MS has all the relevant info. [Here is the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/share-model-driven-app)

In addition you can [Check User Access To Model-driven Apps (D365 CE)](https://meganvwalker.com/checking-users-access-to-model-driven-apps-d365-ce/)

Comment: App Access Checker shows the following information and the user still has no access to the app:

Visible: Unknown
License: Unknown
Security: Yes

Comment: that means your user is not addigned correct license. Please assign license and try again.